# How to handle sync distributed transaction in microservices?

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, architecture, microservices, clean-architecture

for a microservices solution in .NET 6 we have a "Customer" and a "Profile" microservice.

- Customers can exist without a Profile
- A Profile cannot exist without a Customer
- We need the customerId in the Profile table
- We need the profileId in the Customer table
- A single endpoint for signUp, this need to create a profile + a customer and return both IDs in case of success

Given this, I'd need to perform both operations synchronously, I don't see viable to send just "Accepted" because the mobile app needs to tell the user if the profile has been created and, if not, what the problem was.

An example of a possible problem: the customer cannot be created because the profile email is in use by another customer (we have 2 concepts here, registration email for profile and a contact email for customers, initially both emails will be the same but in the future customers can change their contact email so we will need somehow handle this scenario)

The main issue now is:

- how to handle both creations?
- could I implement a saga with kafka and run it synchronously?
- May Profile and Customer be actually part of the same microservice?

Regarding the possibility of this being a single microservice:

We have an "Employees" microservice, we may want, in the future, have profile data specific for employees